# Error Area Code is not set when Creating a virtual Product from Upgrade Schema

Tags: magento2, virtual-products, upgradeschema, create-product, area

I'm using magento 2.2.5 , i want to make a virtual product programmatically using `UpgradeSchema` , but i alws got an error

```
Upgrading data.. Area code is not set
```

when i run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

here's my **UpgradeSchema.php**

```
<?php


namespace Lime\Merchant\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.1", "<")) {
          // $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
          // $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
          // if(!$state->getAreaCode()) {
            $state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);
          }
          $this->createVirtualProduct();
        }
    }

    public function createVirtualProduct()
    {
      $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
      $_product->setName('E-Book');
      $_product->setTypeId('virtual');
      $_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
      $_product->setSku('ebook');
      $_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
      $_product->setVisibility(4);
      $_product->setPrice(1000);
      $_product->setStockData(array(
          'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
          'manage_stock' => 0, //manage stock
          'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
          'qty' => 100000, //qty
          'tax_class_id' => 0
          )
      );

      $_product->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using UpgradeData instead of UpgradeSchema.

Your **UpgradeData.php** looks like:

```
<?php
namespace Lime\Merchant\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    private $productFactory;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * UpgradeData constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if ($context->getVersion() && version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0 ) {
            $this->createVirtualProduct();
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

    public function createVirtualProduct()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
        $product->setName('E-Book');
        $product->setTypeId('virtual');
        $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
        $product->setSku('ebook');
        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
        $product->setVisibility(4);
        $product->setPrice(1000);
        $product->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                'manage_stock' => 0, //manage stock
                'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                'qty' => 100000, //qty
                'tax_class_id' => 0
            )
        );

        $this->productRepository->save($product);
    }
}
```